# How do I change the primary key?

Tags: 7, database

I have created an update that adds a fields to an existing database table. I would like to add that field to the list of primary keys already defined. How do I do this? Do I need to execute the following code?

```
db_drop_primary_key('table_name');
db_change_field('table_name', 'field_name', 'field_name',
array('type' => 'int', 'not null' => TRUE, 'unsigned' => TRUE),
array('primary key' => array(...list of field names...)));
```

I essentially recreate either an existing field or the new one I just added. Is there a simpler method where I can just add the field name to primary key list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very close. In a [hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7):

```
// Drop all primary keys.
db_drop_primary_key('table_name');
// Add primary keys.
db_add_primary_key('table_name', array('field_a', 'field_b'...);
```

See [db_drop_primary_key](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_drop_primary_key/7) and [db_add_primary_key](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_primary_key/7) for details and links to usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am little new here... forgive me if its silly question but do I have to  use hook_update to do this ..? @jonpeck

Comment: Yes if you have already defined the primary key in the hook_schema().